# MySQL String match percentage

Tags: sql, mysql

In MySQL, how can I compare two strings and get matching percentage. Something like this:

```
compare(needle, haystack) = percentage

compare("foo", "food") = 0.75
compare("foo", "foobar") = 0.5
compare("foo", "foofoo") = 1.0
compare("foo", "fo") = 0.0
```

I hope you get the idea :)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Please see:

- [Levenshtein Distance as a MySQL stored function](http://codejanitor.com/wp/2007/02/10/levenshtein-distance-as-a-mysql-stored-function/)

Comment: Perhaps it will give the poster an idea of how to proceed?

Comment: CodeJanitor.com is for sale

Answer (score -1):

On http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#552 you can find the Levenshtein function including a helper function that calculates the ratio of similarity, which is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Although the two last results won't be produced by any algorithm I know of. But they would be really simple to make. The first is string repition the other one is str1.length > str2.length